# Odoo Point of Sale + Posbox : How to modify receipt

Tags: odoo

I need to modify the receipt of Point of sale

In Odoo point of sale, the are two templates to print receipt :
XmlReceipt and PosTicket

As I use a Posbox I guess I have to modify  XmlReceipt.
I wonder if there is a way to inherit the original template ?
I found examples on how to do it with PosTicket template but Xmlreceipt doesnt seem to work the same way.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I extends template "PosTicket", find element by t-jquery, replace with my data (Add "Free" to product's name)

```
<templates id="template" >
<t t-extend="PosTicket">
    <t t-jquery=".receipt-orderlines .product_line" t-operation="inner">
        <t t-if="orderline.get_reward() and orderline.get_reward().type == 'gift'">Free </t>
        <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().display_name"/>
    </t>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know  XmlReceipt and PosTicket templates are both defined in pos.xml so you can inherit both of them in a same way.
Example of inheriting XmlReceipt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="myReceiptTemplate" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="XmlReceipt">
        "your code here"
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The [Qweb doc](https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/web/qweb/)  explains that the directive has to use "t-jquery=selector" based on " a CSS selector into the parent template". But I think XmlReceipt doenst have  a CSS ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I found a solution. 
Example to print the unit price with tax included,  I wrote my xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="myReceiptTemplate" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="XmlReceipt">
         <t t-jquery="t[t-esc='line.price']" t-operation="replace">
            <t t-esc='line.price_with_tax / line.quantity ' />
        </t>      
    </t>
</templates>
```