# Printing barcode on odoo pos receipt

Tags: odoo, barcode

I need to print a barcode on Odoo (v8) **pos receipt using posbox**.
I tried like this :

```
<barcode encoding="CODE39"><t t-esc='receipt.coupon_code'/></barcode>
```

Result : Nothing is printed . But if I make a test like :

```
<barcode encoding="CODE39">*123456798*</barcode>
```

It prints the barcode.

I also tried like this without success:

```
 <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('CODE39', receipt.coupon_code, 600, 100)" style="width:300px;height:50px"/>
```

Any advice ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In fact,

```
<barcode encoding="CODE39"><t t-esc='receipt.coupon_code'/></barcode>
```

works perfectly...

The problem was the length of receipt.coupon_code.

For information, this coupon_code is randomly generated .
It prints successfully the barcode with an 8 digits code, starting and ending with "*" ( `*12345678*`, for example)

Comment: When I add this in my xml file under the PosTicket template it only prints the *12345678* on my receipt..

Comment: Did you use this code : <barcode encoding="CODE39">*123456798*</barcode>

Comment: Maybe you could read this post too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459989/odoo-point-of-sale-posbox-how-to-modify-receipt?rq=1

Comment: Thanks I got this to work! But now I was wondering how did you write to the receipt.coupon_code. I cannot seem to find any 'receipt' model. So how did you defined the variable coupon_code?

Answer (score 0):

I created one receipt and I know how to write barcode in receipt for that you have to convert your barcode in image and then split it. You have to make changes in .xml file. Steps are as follow:

Convert this code in image using `<img>` tag after then split that like this:

```
<img t-if="field_name" t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s&amp;humanreadable=%s' % ('Code128', field_name.split(' ')[1], 600, 100, 1)" style="width:300px;height:50px"/>
```

Here **field_name** is that field of py where your barcode is stored.